# How can I access the Ubuntu filesystem in Windows?

Tags: files, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to access my files from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 from Windows, e.g., using the Windows file explorer.

It works the other way round (Windows file system is under /mnt) but I cannot find the Ubuntu file system in Windows.

Does anyone know where/how I can access it?

Edit: To clarify, I am not talking about a dual-boot setup, but specifically about the new Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10 which is called "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" in the current Insider Preview version

Comment: Just to get this clear: you're talking about a _dual-boot_ system with a Windows partition and an Ubuntu partition, and about accessing the latter while running Windows as the OS. (It would also be possible to dicuss this for the Windows' new _Linux subsystem_, which is actually a stripped down Ubuntu running within a Windows session. In that case it shouldn't be a problem to access any of Ubuntu's files directly from Windows.)

Comment: No, I am not talking about dual-boot, but specifically about the Linux Subsystem in Windows 10 which has the official name "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (at least that's how it is named on my Insider Preview). The question here is where I can find the Ubuntu files in Windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%LocalAppData%\lxss` is the location where your ubuntu installation would be on windows. There is some magic going on with the files though (see: [Alternate Data Streams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105763)) as you can't edit the files from windows otherwise they disappear from the ubuntu environment. I have found that they will come back if you `touch` them from within the ubuntu/bash environment.

Comment: It moved. For later reference, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47193112/954777